# Gridview PageIndex randomly stops working along with other postback controls Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Type: Asp.Net 4.0 - Master page application.

Gridview page indexing randomly stops working and so do "some" other buttons on content page. I can't find a pattern though and this only happens on host server. If I run this on localhost (debugging) I don't have the issue.

So i.e., I can use the page features as intended including searching, sorting, flipping through the page index's and then all of the sudden the page indexing stops working.

Has anyone else had this issue. I am stumped with this one. I've been searching and have only found dead end leads.

NOTE: This seems to be only happening in IE11 browser. FireFox and Chrome works just fine.

Comment: Are you creating / recreating controls dynamically? And are you doing full postbacks when you do this, or partial postbacks with UpdatePanels?  I'm wondering if you're having issues with ViewState (either getting corrupted, or growing too large and causing problems).

Comment: It is hard to say anythings. You may show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was nothing wrong with the application but rather in the framework version vs. the IE version. Framework 4.0 not compatible with IE11. I used the IE11 debugger to find out it was erroring on __doPostBacks. When I changed the emulation in IE11 down to IE9 the application worked as intended, and by the way it worked in FF and Chrome without having to do anything. The simple answer is upgrade to Framework 4.5 for IE11 or secondly is to get the Hotfix. Here are a few links for further explanation:

1. [Link 1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx)
2. [Link 2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1934887.aspx?Server%20patch%20for%20ASP%20NET%204%20to%20help%20it%20recognise%20IE11)
3. [Link 3](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/01/ie11-browser-detection-aspnet)